# Bootstrap & Angular - Accordion toggle not on heading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic Bootstrap accordion in my Angular App.

By default, the accordion gets triggered by the 'heading'. I want to be able to trigger the accordion for an icon:

```
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-ng-click="selectItem()">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"></span>
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </a>
  </h4>
```

This works fine (in a way), but it doesn't give me the result I'm looking for.

In my application, people will be able to select the item by clicking on the heading, while clicking on the 'trigger' will display the children of that specific item (and not select it).

If I leave the code like it is, the item is selected once I click the accordion trigger (which is an expected result I guess).

I'm looking for a solution to make the item selectable while keeping the accordion (which won't select the item). I've tried using event.stopPropagation, but while it stops the item from being selectable using the trigger, the accordion doesn't work anymore.

**Plunkr:** http://plnkr.co/edit/GyuYP1sT6JWaZdLcTCS4?p=preview

Any ideas?

Comment: All you have to do is to move the `icon` above the `<a data-ng-click="selectItem()">`. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hLfkQBcT6tFx28gTgyeC?p=preview)... Or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: I feel like an idiot... I didn't think of that because I wanted to keep everything in the **<a>** tag for styling purposes. Is there any other way? I would need to modify the HTML, which isn't that hard... I just thought there was a way !

Comment: And actually, even modifying the HTML won't work. I need the <a> tag to be fully selectable, and in this case, once you hover on the trigger, the <a> tag is not on the 'hover' state anymore... so the styling disappears

I have updated the plunker to reflect the styling I require

Comment: By "fully selectable", do you mean than even the header background should select the item? Because as a compromise, if you wrap the link text in a `<span>` and move `data-ng-click` there, the icon will no longer change selection. The hover effect will work, but only the text will be clickable this way.

Comment: Actually, the header background should also select the item, as if the text is in display: block;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oU9hAjkm75JWkpnYehTI?p=preview)

Moved the chevron out of the "selecting area", and created a "title-bar" `span` that highlights pink on `hover` and blue on `click` without changing color of chevron arrow.

The chevron arrow only affects the accordian, while the title-bar only affects highlight and selection.

That is my interpretation of what you want. LMK if I am off.

```
    <div sclass="" ng-class=" itemSelected ? 'item active' : 'item inactive'">
      <div class="acc-toggle">
        <a  class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="display: inline-block" 
          data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        </a>
      </div>
      <span class="title-bar" data-ng-click="selectItem()"  sng-class="{ 'active': itemSelected,  'inactive': itemSelected==false  }" >
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </span>
    </div>
```

And made the `span` child turn pink on `hover` and blue on `click`

```
.acc-toggle {
  background-color: 
  white; display: inline-block ; 
  padding: 5px;
}

.title-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 90%;
}
.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
}
.item span {
  display: inline-block;
}
.item.active {
  background: blue;
}
.item.active:hover  {
  background: blue;
}
.item.inactive:hover  {
  background: pink;
}
```